# How to intercept all links and direct to my Android app, via both the "complete action using" and "share via" menus?

Tags: android, android-intent, hyperlink, try-catch, intercept

I'm trying to catch links from apps and direct them to mine. Even though I've implement the  details everyone suggested, I just couldn't get it to work.

I have the following intent filter in my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="http"
              android:host="*"
              android:pathPrefix="*" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

I can catch links that are shared, my app gets listed on the "share via" list, but it doesn't get listed on the "complete action using" list.

I have also tried adding host and pathPrefix but it didn't work that way either.

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried separating the HTTP related things and the SENDTO things into separate intent-filters?

Comment: Yes. I've also tried removing the SENDTO action completely, just to see if they contradicted in any possible way, still doesn't get listed on the "complete action using" list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `pathPrefix` takes a prefix. Hence, your `<intent-filter>` will only support URLs that begin with an asterisk in their path, which will be few URLs, if any.

Second, as OrhanC1 indicated, this should be at least two `<intent-filter>` elements, one for `VIEW` and one for `SENDTO`. In truth, you need three:

1. `VIEW` + (`BROWSABLE` and `DEFAULT`)
2. (`SEND` and `SENDTO`) + `DEFAULT`
3. `MAIN` + `LAUNCHER`

Comment: Loved you at Apps World London, bro!

Comment: Thank you both so much, it all works now! I've seperated the intent filters and removed the host and pathPrefix attributes, my app is now listed on both lists. Great!